# How to cross compile monero to a ARMv7 target on a x86-64 host?

Tags: linux, build, compile

Is it possible to cross compile the monero source on a x86-64 machine targeting an ARMv7 device?

I tried this command:
`make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-`

But I ended up with x86-64 binaries:

```
$ file monero-wallet-cli
monero-wallet-cli: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=...
```

Also, how does the dev team build the monero binaries for the ARM architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Makefile is actually just a wrapper around CMake. If you look inside, it has various ARM targets like:

```
release-static-linux-armv7
release-static-linux-armv8
release-static-android-armv7
...
```

So you would run something like:

```
make release-static-linux-armv7
```

To build for ARMv7 Linux.

There is also a section in the [README](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/README.md#cross-compiling) on cross-compiling using the *depends* build system:

> `make depends target=arm-linux-gnueabihf` for armv7 binaries. Requires: g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf

Comment: I used the `make depends target=arm-linux-gnueabihf` command and had a few dependencies missing (`autoconf automake...`) which I resolved,  then following error occurred:

`-- Looking for libunbound
-- Found libunbound include (unbound.h) in /usr/include
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:59 (message):
  Found libunbound includes, but could not find libunbound library.
  Please make sure you have installed libunbound or libunbound-dev or the
  equivalent
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  external/CMakeLists.txt:77 (die)`

Although I do have `libunbound-dev` installed

Comment: If you are following instructions in the README, and they are not working, raise a ticket in [GitHub issues](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues).

Comment: The answer is correct, but I couldn't build with `BACKCOMPAT` enabled. I created an [issue](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/5427)